# SQL query syntax errors when dealing with subpopulations

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm a software tester using this SQL query to check some data in our db:

```
select * from (
select sum(case when qm.HEALTHY_TERM_NEWBORN='E' then 1 else 0 end) as num, -- choose measure status columns here as appropriate
sum(case when qm.HEALTHY_TERM_NEWBORN  in ('D','E') then 1 else 0 end) as denom,
-- summary level columns
cms.FACILITY_GROUP_ID,
-- time period columns
dt.USA_FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN_DT
from F_MU_QM_EH_2014_IP_ADMSN qm
inner join CMS_MU_INFO cms on qm.DISCHARGE_CMS_MU_ID=cms.CMS_MU_ID
inner join DATE_DIMENSION dt on dt.CALENDAR_DT=qm.DISCHARGE_DATE
-- do filtering here if any
where cms.FACILITY_GROUP_ID='130170' AND dt.USA_FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN_DT='10/01/2013'
group by -- summary level grouping
cms.FACILITY_GROUP_ID,
-- time period grouping
dt.USA_FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN_DT
) x 
where denom is not null
```

The script returns aggregated data from one column of information; however, for some of my testing I need to filter the column based on another column that defines a subpopulation within the first column. I tried this:

```
select * from (
sum(case when qm.SCIPINF1='E' and qm.SCIPINF1_POPULATION_C=7 then 1 else 0 end) as num
sum(case when qm.SCIPINF1 in ('D','E') and qm.SCIPINF1_POPULATION_C=1 then 1 else 0 end) as denom
-- summary level columns
cms.FACILITY_GROUP_ID,
-- time period columns
dt.USA_FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN_DT
from F_MU_QM_EH_2014_IP_ADMSN qm
inner join CMS_MU_INFO cms on qm.DISCHARGE_CMS_MU_ID=cms.CMS_MU_ID
inner join DATE_DIMENSION dt on dt.CALENDAR_DT=qm.DISCHARGE_DATE
-- do filtering here if any
where cms.FACILITY_GROUP_ID='130170' AND dt.USA_FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN_DT='10/01/2013'
group by -- summary level grouping
cms.FACILITY_GROUP_ID,
-- time period grouping
dt.USA_FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN_DT
) x 
where denom is not null
```

But I'm getting a syntax error near 'sum' according to Oracle, and I'm missing a parenthesis according to MS SQL Server Management Studio. Do any of you beautiful internet people know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `comma` between two columns and also `select` in `sub-select`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Sum(CASE   -- select missing here
                     WHEN qm.SCIPINF1 = 'E'
                          AND qm.SCIPINF1_POPULATION_C = 7 THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                   END) AS num, --comma missing here
               Sum(CASE
                     WHEN qm.SCIPINF1 IN ( 'D', 'E' )
                          AND qm.SCIPINF1_POPULATION_C = 1 THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                   END) AS denom, --comma missing here
               -- summary level columns
               cms.FACILITY_GROUP_ID,
               -- time period columns
               dt.USA_FISCAL_YEAR_BEGIN_DT
```

Comment: Sorry, it had the comma initially, but I kept getting "incorrect syntax near ','" so I took it out. What do you mean by select in subselect?